# Two Composite Primary Key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I am trying to define table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[User]
(
  Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Name nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [Group] 
(
  Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Name nvarchar(1024) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [UserToGroup]
(
  Name VARCHER(20)
  UserId int NOT NULL,
  GroupId int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( UserId, Name),
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( GroupId, Name),
  FOREIGN KEY ( UserId ) REFERENCES [User] ( Id ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY ( GroupId ) REFERENCES [Group] ( Id ) ON UPDATE  NO ACTION  ON DELETE  CASCADE
);
```

How can i create table with two Composite Primary Key?

Comment: Primary pretty much means "1".  A table can have only one primary key (which can consist of multiple columns).  My preference is for a single numeric synthetic key, but that is another matter..  Just call them `NOT NULL` with a `UNIQUE` constraint and call it a day.

Comment: do u mean somthing like?
  NOT NULL UNIQUE   ( UserId, Name),
  NOT NULL UNIQUE ( GroupId, Name),

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have a composite key with all three fields?

Comment: Because that composite key with all three fields it's completely another meaning

Comment: If `UserToGroup` does what I think it does, then neither `( UserId, Name)` or `( GroupId, Name)` should be enforced as unique on this table. Your table is unique on `(UserID, GroupID)` only. There are no other unique keys in this table. We'd have to see the data for sure but the table name and columns make its intention pretty clear. Try to explain what you are you trying to achieve here with those two 'primary key clustered' lines.

Comment: Just makes no sense.  The PK should be UserId, GoupId and then just put a unique constraint on Name.

Comment: @Frisbee, That would be very different to what is proposed in the question. What makes you think that name is supposed to be unique in this case?

Comment: @sqlvogel Common sense

Comment: @Frisbee, fair enough but a unique name for each combination of user and group seems a bit unlikely to me and I don't see any reason to second-guess the user's design. Either way, it doesn't alter the essence of the question which is how to create the second key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 UserId int NOT NULL,
 GroupId int NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE ( UserId, Name),
 UNIQUE ( GroupId, Name)
```

In the relational model and in SQL there is no logical difference between one key and another so there's no very strong reason to have a different syntax for specifying one key over any other. However, for better or worse, the authors of the SQL standard decided to make a limitation that the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint syntax can only be used once per table and that where you need more than one key you have to use one or more `UNIQUE` constraints instead. Arguably it would be desirable to drop that limitation but since it's fundamentally just a bit of syntactical sugar that's unlikely to happen any time soon.